# Other file formats with the gradle license plugin

Tags: gradle

using license gradle plugin,

If we want to include other types of files like .js, .xsl, .rptdesign etc., also to add the license text, what do we need to do? Please any one can suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the instructions](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin#recognizing-other-file-types), they say:

> An extensive list of formats and mappings are available by default, see the [SupportedFormats link](https://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/wiki/SupportedFormats). Occasionally a project might need to add a mapping to a unknown file type to an existing comment style.
>
> ```
> license {
>   mapping {
>     javascript='JAVADOC_STYLE'
>   }
> }
> // or
> license.mapping 'javascript' 'JAVADOC_STYLE'
> // or directly on the task
> licenseMain.mapping 'javascript' 'JAVADOC_STYLE'
> ```
>
> Defining new comment types is not currently supported, but file a bug and it can be added.

Comment: I have added to build.gradle

Comment: license {
  mapping {
    javascript='JAVADOC_STYLE'
 xml='XML_STYLE'
 xsl='XML_STYLE'
 html='XML_STYLE'
  }
} but not adding license.txt in the xml,xsl,html files

Comment: also when i write in build.gradle                  registerLicense('js', licenseFormat('/*', ' *', ' */')) getting error Could not find method licenseFormat() for arguments [/*,  *,  */] on root project

Comment: @RajuKothapeta And where in the instructions for the gradle plugin have you seen `registerLicense` or `licenseFormat`?

Comment: That used to be the old way (but that's been a few releases)... (I'm the writer/maintainer of the plugin).

Comment: @HieryNomus Ahhh, so he's reading the instructions for an old version (and not the instructions I repeatedly link to)

Comment: @tim_yates I guess so, cause there is no reference anymore to either `registerLicense` or `licenseFormat`. That no longer exists.

Comment: I have read the insturctions from https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/blob/master/license.gradle

Comment: Hiery Nomus can you give the link how to add license.mapping other files like xml,xsl,html and how to run.thanks Raju

Comment: Hi all am able to add license for html,xml,xsl,js files.But not able to add licence for  .rptdesign pattern files.can any one help me.